# How to utilize product code with url-key for more effective urls?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.8, ee-1.13

Below is a typical Magento Product Url:

```
http://magesite.com/pretty-product-name
```

While this is a nice clean url, it seems kind of risky relying solely on a url-key. There's so many ways a url-key can get mangled (characters cut off, reformatted, etc) but ID's seem to stick around. **How would you implement some sort of id in the url?** It seems to me a lot of sites do this. (Like Below):

```
http://magesite.com/product/123/pretty-product-name
http://magesite.com/p/123/pretty-product-name

http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00DN3KHP4
http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00DN3KHP4/Some-Url-Title
```

### So the following user scenarios could happen:

Browser Attempt: `http://magesite.com/p/123/pretty-produc` **[No Url-Key Found]** Site can use the product ID to 301 redirect to `http://magesite.com/product/123/pretty-product-name`

Browser Attempt: `http://magesite.com/p/123` **[No Url-Key Exists]** Site can use the product ID to 301 redirect to `http://magesite.com/product/123/pretty-product-name`

Browser Attempt: `http://magesite.com/p/123/old-product-description` **[No Url-Key Exists]** Site can use the product ID to 301 redirect to `http://magesite.com/product/123/pretty-product-name`

**Background**

I'm new to Magento, using EE 1.13.. Our previous platform (Custom Coded) did the above and thought it was great.

**Notes**
The Amazon example I used lacks the redirect which I think it pretty powerful for SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there aren't any url rewrites in the table `core_url_rewrite` for a specific product then the url generated for the product is:  `catalog/product/view/id/123/s/product-url-key-here`.
Maybe you can disable the generation of URL rewrites for the products and use this fallback url